# mongoose update model before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model:

```
const wordSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  author: {type: Object, default: 'unknown'},
  quote: String,
  source: {type: String, default: 'unknown', index: true},
  rating: {type: Number, default: 0},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

Now after receiving a POST request to my server, I want to make a GET request to wikipedia, and get the author info, then append it to my model as an object, and write this model into my database.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let author = {};
  let quote = new Word({
    author: req.body.author,
    quote: req.body.quote,
    source: req.body.source,
    rating: req.body.rating,
  });
  let authorName = req.body.author.replace(/ /g, '%20');
  let url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=' + authorName + '&prop=pageimages|extracts&pithumbsize=200&exsentences=10&exintro=true';
  request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      return error;
    }
    let data = JSON.parse(body);
    let pageID;
    for(page in data.query.pages) {
      pageID = page;
    }
    author = {
      name: req.body.author,
      thumbnail: data.query.pages[pageID].thumbnail.source,
      flavorText: data.query.pages[pageID].extract,
    };
  });
  // Save the quote
  quote.pre('save', (next) => {
    this.author = author;
  })
  quote.save(function(err, quote) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/words');
  });
});
```

Now I tried updating the value with the `.pre` function, but I am getting

> quote.pre is not a function

What would be the 'correct way of doing this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quote` is not a Mongoose schema, but `wordSchema` is so it needs to be as follow:

```
wordSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  this.quote = whteverYouWantToAssignWith;
})
```

But actually you don't need it in your use case as far as I understand, you may achieve what you want as follow:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let authorName = req.body.author.replace(/ /g, '%20');
  let url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=' + authorName + '&prop=pageimages|extracts&pithumbsize=200&exsentences=10&exintro=true';
  request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      return error;
    }
    let data = JSON.parse(body);
    let pageID;
    for(page in data.query.pages) {
      pageID = page;
    }

    let quote = new Word({
      author: {
        name: req.body.author,
        thumbnail: data.query.pages[pageID].thumbnail.source,
        flavorText: data.query.pages[pageID].extract,
      },
      quote: req.body.quote,
      source: req.body.source,
      rating: req.body.rating,
    });

    quote.save(function(err, quote) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/words');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: with this, I am just getting wordSchema is not defined

Comment: You need to put this piece of code where the schema is defined of course not inside request function.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I move the whole http request function to the schema file?

Comment: Actually you don't need to use `pre` in this use-case, check my answer above.